# The Graph component in react-graph-vis doesn't reload when the state changes

Tags: reactjs, vis.js

I'm working on a React component that wraps the `Graph` component of [react-graph-vis](https://github.com/crubier/react-graph-vis). My component is supposed to render a certain graph and to provide a button for adding a node to the graph.

A simplified version of what I've done is the following component which renders a (single node) graph and a button. Clicking on the button is supposed to add a second node to the graph.

```
class GraphWrapper extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
      var graph = {nodes: [{id: 1, label: '1'}], edges: []};
      this.state = {
         options: {},
         graph: graph
      };
   }

   addNode() {
      var graph = this.state.graph;
      graph.nodes.push({id: 2, label: '2'});
      this.setState({});
   }

   render() {
      return <div>
                <Graph graph={this.state.graph}, options={this.state.options}/>
                <button onClick={this.addNode.bind(this)}>Add Node</button>
             </div>;
   }
}
```

The initial graph is being rendered properly. Also, clicking on the button changes the state as expected. However, the graph visualization doesn't change, the second node doesn't show up, and it seems as if the `<Graph/>` component isn't being re-rendered despite the change in the state.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should always treat the React state as if it was immutable. In your case you are mutating the state, meaning that the references `this.state.graph` and `this.state.graph.nodes` are the same even though the array content has changed.

A better version of `addNode`:

```
 addNode() {
      var nodesCopy = this.state.graph.nodes.slice(); // this will create a copy with the same items
      nodesCopy.push({id: 2, label: '2'});
      this.setState({ graph: {nodes: nodesCopy, edges: []};);
   }
```

Notice that, because of the fact that you changed the `nodes` reference, as now it points to a new array, you are forced to cascade it up, changing every reference until the root of the state.

**EDIT**

In the previous version of this answer I implied that React woudn't rerender if the state "references" didn't change. That is not correct. `setState` will always cause a rerender. **However**, individual components may **opt** for not updating if the props they receive don't change.

Regarding your comment @snakile, the most likely reason for what you described is that the `Graph` component implemented a [shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState)](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) in such a way that, if the reference of the prop `graph` didn't change, then the component wouldn't update. This would explain why your button updated while `Graph` did not.

Comment: There's something I don't fully understand. You're saying that in my version of `addNode` React is not supposed to re-render anything (as the `graph` object didn't really change). Nevertheless, in my actual code, the text on the button displayed the number of nodes in the graph (`{this.state.graph.nodes.length}`). The text on the button did increment from 1 to 2 when clicking on it. Doesn't it mean that react re-rendered the button because it had detected a change in the state?